# MySQLWorkbench - copy column from result grid

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

In MySQLWorkbench 6.3.4 on OS X, is it possible to copy a single column of the Result Grid to clipboard, e.g. for pasting into Excel? The issue is selecting the column, not the pasting into another application.

I have seen this done on the Windows version but have not found a solution for OS X.

Comment: How exactly can you copy one column to the clipboard in the Windows version? Don't know of such way. 
Why not just SELECT the single column you wish to get in the results, and then export as csv file? you can then open the csv file in Excel.

Comment: You can't select the single column in Mac Os. But you can do it in Windows

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the different export methods are described [in the docs, here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-admin-export-import.html). As for simple copy-n-pasting, I just performed this using 6.3.4 on OS X and rows ended up looking like the following in my clipboard:

```
'1', 'PENELOPE', 'GUINESS', '2006-02-15 04:34:33'
'2', 'NICK', 'WAHLBERG', '2006-02-15 04:34:33'
```

In that case I selected two rows, right-clicked on the selection, and chose "Copy Row". You cannot select an individual column, but you could adjust your query to output one column.

Comment: This is how to copy rows, not column as been asked